# How can I find all necessary columns for creating a unique index?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables in an oracle database and in those tables, there are varying amounts of columns. In the tables, there are real-world data (1 million - 1 billion rows)
I want to create a unique index for every table, but I don't know what column or columns are contains uniqe data.

The goal is to find the minimal amount of columns for a table, with which I can create a unique index.

My idea is to create a select statement for every column and examine how many different values it has:

```
select COLUMN_1, count(1) CC from TABLE group by COLUMN_1;
```

This way, I know the number of records in the table, and by dividing that with this query result, I get a number that indicates uniqueness of a column. After doing this for all columns, I list the columns in order by they uniqueness until every row becomes unique.

Are there any better way, or already existing algorithm to do this?

Comment: I would add a generated unique id column for each table, instead of relying on existing data's uniqueness

Comment: There is a unique id column for the tables, but for foreign key referencing we use this unique index's columns

Comment: Then I think you'll be running into some headaches... what about hashing the concatenation of all columns ?

Comment: Using all the unique index's columns instead of the unique id is against best practice I would say. Do you have a specific reason to do that?

Comment: There may not actually _be_ a unique set of columns. Stacking them up in order of uniqeness is not the right thing to do either.

Comment: This is a data warehouse project, and we create a unique index and a constraint to the table. And these columns are indexed.

Comment: If this is a data warehouse, then your data should be modelled and it should not be a mystery which columns are unique, In a dimension,the surrogate key would be one unique value and the source system key would be another unique value,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, yes, this one:

```
select COLUMN_1, count(1) CC from TABLE group by COLUMN_1;
```

Will get you a count of unique values. The closest this count is to total table count, the more uniqueness you have. So this:

```
select COLUMN_1, count(1)/n_table_total_count uniqueness_ratio from TABLE group by COLUMN_1;
```

Will actually give you the uniqueness_ratio of the column data. 1 means unique, anything less means no unique. The closest to 1 the more distinct the values are.

So running this to all columns you get uniqueness ratio for all columns.
If you have one or more columns with a value of one you can use this one or many of them or any other combination you like and you have your primary key.

If however no column has uniqueness_ratio = 1 then you need to search again. That is, getting the 2 (or 3 or 4) closest to be unique columns does not guarantee that their combination of data is unique:

ColA, uniqueness_ratio = 0.9999656743556
ColB, uniqueness_ratio = 0.94632

Those columns both have some rows with the same value. Few, but they do.
One of the rows that have same values at ColA, may also happen to have same values at ColB. Rare, but possible. So you need to run:

```
select ColA, ColB, count(1)/n_table_total_count uniqueness_ratio from TABLE group by ColA, ColB;
```

If uniqueness_ratio = 1 then this column combination can be used as primary key. If not, you need another combination.

So clearly, you need to make up combinations with some logic, and run additional statements to get a uniqueness_ratio = 1. Perhaps this logic could be take best 2, if not take best 3 and so on. Where 'best' = closest to uniqueness_ratio = 1, higher value in other words.

You are going to need a lot of sets of statements, so I suggest you create a procedure that creates a text you can either print and/or execute (dynamic sql).

Note that this method may still not work if uniqueness is not possible even if all columns get involved but still there is at least 1 duplicate row.

This method will not guarantee that future data may be inserted. If a future row violates the selected primary key it would not be inserted.

Preferably you should consider the option to add a new column with generated unique values as primary key. This will surely succeed and all future data are welcome.

Finally pay attention to clustering. Oracle database always uses the primary key as the clustering key. This means physically re-arrange the data to the disk. And, if performance is a root reason for adding primary keys, it is also worth checking partitions. It is worth the try since adding PKs is not going to be an easy or fast task.

Answer (score 0):

**Identify right columns**

To identify the right columns my usual trick is to use the ROW_NUMBER() [Oracle Analytic Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions).

Using a column like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <column1>[, <column2>...] ORDER BY (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)) AS <your column name here>
```

This generates a unique count. As with windowing functions this requires either a sub query or a common table expression first. Then subsequently select only the rows  where the window function is greater than 1.
Any such rows means the index would not be unique.

**Index strategies**

If there are more than 3 (around, depends) columns in the unique index or a character column with more than 5 characters in the index then better build a surrogate key, especially if the data set has lots of rows.
This key is easier to traverse if of type integer or bigint.

On top build a separate unique index in the right order (or multiple non-unique indexes) over the primary surrogate key to facilitate queries.